# A dual basis of the set of polynomials of degree two

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

**Question**

Let $T:\mathbb{R}[x]_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[x]_n$ be linear ($\mathbb{R}[x]_n$ is the space of polynomials degree n with real coefficients). Show that the following two maps are in the dual space of $\mathbb{R}[x]_n$:$$\delta(f)=f(0),~~\delta_T(f)=(Tf)(0) \text{ where } f\in\mathbb{R}[x]_n.$$
Here $f(0)$ means $f$ is evaluated at $x=0$. Furthermore let, let $n=2$ and let $T=D^2$ where $Df=\frac{df}{dx}$. Find the representation of $[\delta_T]_{B^*}$, where $B^*$is the dual basis of $B=\{1,x,x^2\}$.

**Attempt**

I think I have managed the first part of the question just fine, showing that the two maps are in the dual space. All I have to do is show that the result is a scalar and that the map is linear right?

The second part is where I get a little confused.. I thought a suitable dual basis would be $$B^*=\{\left.\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^{(n)}f}{dx^{(n)}}\right|_{~x=0}\}\text{  for } n=0,1,2.$$
In which case $[\delta_T]_{B^*}=(0,0,2)$ right? or would it be a matrix?

In any case, i'm confused because couldn't someone have easily picked another dual basis that still satisfies the condition that its action on the original basis set gives a 0 or 1 as according to the Kronecker delta? and then wouldn't the representation be something other than (0,0,2) ? is this question not subjective? Thanks for any help.

Comment: OK. So the matrix form of $[\delta_T]_{B^*}$ can be determined by its action on the elements of $B^*$.

$$\text{ Let } f=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \in \mathbb{R}[x]_2\\$$
$$\text{Then } \delta_T(B^*_1)=\delta_T(f(0))=D^2f|_{x=0}=2a_2$$
$$\text{ And } \delta_T(B^*_2)=D^3f|_{x=0}=0$$
$$\text{ And }  \delta_T(B^*_3)=D^4f|_{x=0}=0$$
$$\text{ Which would mean that: } [\delta_T]_{B^*}=\begin{bmatrix} 2a_2&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{Does this look correct at all to you? }$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the statement of the question: Since $\delta_T \in (\Bbb R[x]_n)^*$, it is a map $\Bbb R[x]_n \to \Bbb R$, and hence is an $(n + 1) \times 1$, i.e., a row matrix with $n + 1$ entries, as you say. In particular, yes, for $T = D^2$, $$[\delta_T]_{B^*} = \pmatrix{0&0&2}.$$

Comment: Anyway, the answer to the penultimate question is that a choice of basis $B$ determines a *unique* dual basis $B^*$.